# Default constructor parameters

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <vector>

class A {
private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
public:
    A(int size = 100, int init_val = 100){
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
            v_.push_back(init_val);
    }
};
```

In the main, if I do:

```
A a(1000, 100);
```

What really happens? It is the first time I've seen hardcoded parameters in a constructor!

Comment: I'd suggest to change the title of question to `Default values of constructor parameters` (and content accordingly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The passed values will simply replace default values of parameters with the passed ones.

- A definition `A a;` will result in call to `A::A(100, 100)`
- A definition `A a(5);` will result in call to `A::A(5, 100)`
- A definition `A a(5, 6);` will result in call to `A::A(5, 6)`

Answer (score 4):

Those aren't "hardcoded", just default parameters.  If you don't supply the parameters, then `size` defaults to 100, and `init_val` to 100.  Parameters that you *do* supply override the defaults.  Hence:

```
A a1();            // size = 100, init_val = 100
A a2(1000);        // size = 1000, init_val = 100
A a3(1000, 1000);  // size = 1000, init_val = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
A(int size = 100, int init_val = 100)
```

does not define "hardcoded parameters", but rather *default* values. If you call `A::A()` leaving the parameters away, the compiler will use the default values. That's all there is to it.